# What does the '()', which I use red arows and green rectangle to mark in the picture, represent in the Java API doc?

Tags: java, doc

There are many words like '(Class1,Class2)' in JAVA API docs. What do these words represent?

[image]
What does the '()', which I use red arows and green rectangle to mark in the picture, represent in the Java API doc?

Comment: The `()` go around the method parameters, same as most `()` in Java.

Comment: It's standard notation to refer to an _overload_ of a _method_. Do you know what "overload" and "method" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cancel is a method, so its called as cancel() with parameters inside the parentheses.

`cancel(String, Throwable)` means that its a cancel method with a String as a first parameter and a Throwable as a second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There are the parameters the method take. Here `cancel` takes a `String` and a `Throwable` as parameters

From a method like this, you take just `method(String a, String b)`

```
static void method(String a, String b) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a method signature:

```
public abstract void cancel(@Nullable String message, @Nullable Throwable cause)
```